# fixed point iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

So I am meant to write a Matlab function that has a starting guess p and tolerance e as inputs and outputs the number of iterations n and final fixed point approx pn satisfying abs(pn-pn-1) <= e for a given function g. Here is what I currently have:

```
function f = fixed(p,e)
i=1;
pn=g(p);
while (abs(pn - p) <= e)
    pn = g(p)
    i=i+1;
    p=pn
end
end
```

But I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Do I need to include another if statement in the case that the absolute difference is >e? What else would I include in such a statement?

Comment: I think there is a subtle bug in your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function f = fixed(p,e)
i=1;
pn=g(p);
while (abs(pn - p) <= e)
    p = pn
    pn=g(p)
    i=i+1;
end
f = pn
end
```

I think you were comparing `p` and `pn` after the `p=pn` statement causing an early exit.